# How to get the CPU time of Delphi program?

Tags: delphi, debugging, time, delphi-xe2

**Problem I'm trying to solve:** My program uses `System.Win.ScktComp.TServerSocket` to communicate with another local process via Ethernet. Between receiving a packet from the local process and sending a response is 100ms--which shouldn't take this long. I'm trying to step through my program with the debugger to see where that 100ms is being spent.

The problem is that if I get the current time while I'm in the debugger it will obviously count the time it spent in the paused state of the debugger. Another problem is that the relevant part of my app is `TTimer` and event-driven so that when a routine returns you're not sure what routine will be called next.

**My attempt:** I can forgo using the debugger and `print` the current time everywhere like in **all** the `OnTimer` procedures and other events.

**Much better solution:** Step through with the debugger, getting the CPU time (which isn't affected by the time spent paused in the debugger) here and there to pinpoint where that 100ms is being lost.

Comment: No, trying to time your app whilst being debugged won't give meaningful results. Instrument this with a profiler or some logging code.

Comment: I would give procmon a try. Start Procmon, start your app, do your thing, stop procmon, open Tools -> Stack Summary and drill down in your application. *(Enable Advanced Output in Filter menu)* If that's not fine grained enough, you can use [WPA](https://www.google.be/search?hl=nl&q=defrag+tools+wpa&sourceid=ie8&rls=com.microsoft:nl-BE:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&gws_rd=ssl) *(albeit with a steeper learning curve)*

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Why can this not be done? In Python can I stop at a breakpoint, print the CPU time with `clock()` (it uses the C stdlib `clock()`) and the time it prints **doesn't** take into account the time it spent paused in the debugger.  @Lieven thank you for your suggestion; didn't know you could use Procmon for this.

Comment: Since you are using Delphi XE2, you have access to some CodeSite logging, implement that with timings and it should be negligible addition to your run time. This way you can also see all output more info if you need it

Comment: Use the [System.Diagnostics.TStopWatch](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Diagnostics.TStopwatch) advanced record to measure the timing. Output via OutputDebugString to a logging system.

Comment: You can do it, but I doubt it will give you very good results. Feel free to do it the way you like. I personally would use instrumentation and logging. If you'd rather do it manually whilst stepping through a debugger, that's entirely up to you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I would like to try it but I still don't know how to get the CPU time when in the debugger (I have yet to verify the Procmon method suggested). @Bernd: Oh thanks, I only switched to XE2 a few months ago and didn't realise how many useful features it has. @LU Thanks, that's more accurate than the `SysUtils.FormatDateTime` I've been using.

Comment: @NewWorld There's a very high probability that your delay is **not** in CPU utilisation, but rather in wait states and context switches. This is why "debugging to find the performance problem" is unlikely to help. _You need to profile the code_.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe that you are tackling your problem the correct way, and have made that point in comments. Leaving that aside, the function that you are asking for is [`GetProcessTimes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to ... see where that 100ms is being spent.

A debugger will not be able to tell you that very easily.  You need to use a profiler instead, like AQTime or similar, and let it clock your code in real-time and report the results, such as how much time was spent in specific functions and class methods.